# [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@2223a639 -> unknown locator]

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am executing the javascript code through selenium webdriver using JavaScriptExecuter.

When I am executing below code getting the error of `RemoteWebElemet`. I don't know why this error is occurring. In code, I am just injecting the js code into the DOM structure by selenium `webdriver` using `JavaScriptExecutor`.

Code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

System.out.println(js.executeScript(
                " var alTag = new Array();"+ "var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('img');" +
                        "for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {" +
                        " if((nodeList[i].getAttribute('alt')== '') || (nodeList[i].getAttribute('alt')== undefined)) {" + " alTag.push(nodeList[i]);"
                        + "}" +"}" + "return alTag ;","RemoteWebElement"
        ));
```

Comment: What does the error says?

Comment: [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@2223a639 -> unknown locator] This is the error